# phpbb3 forum integrated in a custom php script

Tags: php, forum, phpbb3

I am trying to create a forum for my website, but I want to have the forums take only specific space on my page. Not the whole area. Something like 800px width and free height.

Do you think that is possible in some way? I guess what I am trying to say would very much look like this outcome of bridging WP and phpBB.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wz3p0Bq317M

Any hints and/or ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you set the CSS stylesheet correctly you can achieve this, nothing to do with PHP.

You could also load it in an iframe but if it's not the same width you will get scrolling.

Comment: I don't really wanna go into the iframe idea, for several reasons. 
I just want to achieve that without too complicated actions and procedures. The first idea you said, you meant using the forum css and chaing that to fit my size etc? That sounds so time consuming as a solution. Isn't there anything easier?

Comment: not with PHP its a css issue! if the forum uses tables you could also add `width="800"` to the HTML.